# Recoding a dataset with variables of different classes

Tags: r

I'm trying to recode the variables in my datasets. The data is messy and consisted of mixed classes. And I want to tidy all of them into binary numeric variables with 1/0. I have produced a simplified example as follows:

My original data consist of variables of classes character (yes/no), logical (TRUE/FALSE) and numeric (1/0). I want to code everything into 1/0, and the missing values as 0 as well.

```
tmp <- data.frame(x1 = c("Yes","Yes","No","No",NA),
                  x2 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, NA),
                  x3 = c(1,1,0,0,NA))
tmp$x1 <- as.character(tmp$x1)

recode.var <- function(x){
      if (is.character(x)) {
      x <- ifelse(x=="Yes",1,ifelse(x=="No",0,ifelse(is.na(x),0,NA)))
    } 
      if (is.logical(x)) {
      x <- ifelse(x==TRUE,1,ifelse(x==FALSE,0,ifelse(is.na(x),0,NA)))
    } 
      if (is.numeric(x)) {
      x <- ifelse(x==1,1,ifelse(x==0,0,ifelse(is.na(x),0,NA))) 
      }
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  return(x)
}
tmp1 <- data.frame(apply(tmp, 2, recode.var))
```

However, the result is not what I wished.

```
> tmp1
  x1 x2 x3
1  1 NA NA
2  1 NA NA
3  0 NA NA
4  0 NA NA
5 NA NA NA
```

Would appreciate if someone could spot the error in the code. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We don't quite have a reproducible example here yet. What was the code you used to generate `tmp1`? For me, `as.data.frame(lapply(tmp, recode.var))` and `dplyr::mutate_all(tmp, recode.var)` give exactly what I think it is you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spotted at least one small problem with your custom function: if you're using `ifelse`, you need to start off with the `is.na` condition. See this example:

```
x <- c(1, 2, NA)
ifelse(x == 1, "foo", "bar")
# > [1] "foo" "bar" NA
```

Here's an alternative I've made. The `coalesce` function comes from the `dplyr` package.

```
recode.var <- function(x) {
  if (is.character(x)) {
    return(coalesce(as.numeric(x == "Yes"), 0))
  }

  if (is.numeric(x)) {
    return(coalesce(x, 0))
  }

  if (is.logical(x)) {
    return(coalesce(as.numeric(x), 0))
  }

  x
}
```

My version does not deal with values outside the options you've mentioned. I'm assuming they don't exist in your dataset, so they don't need to be accounted for, but do tell me if that's a problem.

The final step is how to apply the function to the dataframe. Using `dplyr` you can use the following:

```
tmp2 <- mutate_all(tmp, recode.var)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `x1` needs to changed. `as.integer` on `x2` will give 1/0. 
Can't we just use something like this:

```
tmp$x1 <- dplyr::recode(tmp$x1, "Yes" = 1, "No" = 0)
tmp$x2 <- as.integer(tmp$x2)
tmp[is.na(tmp)] <- 0
tmp
  x1 x2 x3
1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1
3  0  0  0
4  0  0  0
5  0  0  0
```